# Python Recursion Depth Exceeded in Generate Parenthesis Problem

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am solving [Generate Parenthesis Problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/generate-parentheses/) using Brute Force as follows

```
class Solution:
    def generateParenthesis(self, n: int) -> List[str]:
        C, ans = [], []
        ans = self.generate(C, n, ans)
        return ans
    
    def generate(self, C, n, ans):
        if len(C) == 2*n:
            if self.valid(C):
                ans.append(''.join(C))
        else:
            C.append('(')
            ans = self.generate(C, n, ans)
            C.pop()
            C.append(')')
            ans = self.generate(C, n, ans)
            C.pop()
        return ans
        
        
    def valid(self, C):
        bal = 0
        for c in C:
            if c == '(': bal+=1
            else: bal-=1
            if bal<0: return False
        return bal == 0
```

I am getting the following error

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
Line 8 in generate(solution.py)
```

When I combine Line 8,9 and 10 as follows, I don't get the error anymore.

```
if len(C) == 2*n and self.valid(C):
    ans.append(''.join(C))
```

Seems kinda strange. Why is this happening?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: These `else` part of that if statement will behave differently (will trigger on different conditions) with the changed if.

Comment: This code seems to work fine: https://repl.it/repls/FrostyAgitatedJava

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let n=2

If we construct a recursion tree, the first string that will reach a length of `2*n=2*2=4` is `C="(((("`

Now `C` is of length `2*n` but is not valid

So, the condition 
`len(C) == 2*n and self.valid(C)` is `False`

Now the `else` part will be executed and the program will run into an infinite recursion calls.

PS: Thanks [@Jottbe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6925185/jottbe) for pointing out the logical error

Answer (score 1):

after the code change your program is not anymore logically equivalent to the previous implementation.
Look at the else branch and you'll see, what I mean. In the original version the else branch is executed if:

len(C) != 2*n

in the modified version it is executed if:

len(C) != 2*n or not self.valid(C)

But at the moment I can't see why this change would explain the observed behavior, because it should even produce more calls to generate.

Btw. you don't need the checking logic, if you take into account, that all combinations of ( ) are valid, if the following conditions apply during your iterations:

- at each level of your generate call, you have at max as many closing parenthesis as opening parenthesis
- at each level of your generate call you have at most n opening parenthesis

With this knowledge you can use:

```
class Solution2:
    def generateParenthesis(self, n: int) -> List[str]:
        C, ans = [], []
        ans = self.generate(C, n, ans, 0, 0)
        return ans

    def generate(self, C, n, ans, op, cl):
        #print(n, op, cl)
        if op < n or cl < n:
            if op < n:
                ans = self.generate(C + ['('], n, ans, op+1, cl)
            if op > cl:
                ans = self.generate(C + [')'], n, ans, op,   cl+1)
        else:
            ans.append(''.join(C))
        return ans
```

Comment: Oh no! got it! What a blunder that is! Thank you very much for the help

Comment: I figured out the reason behind unusual behaviour. Thanks!